# Laravel 5.1 Authentication - Token Mistmatch

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a fresh install of Laravel 5.1 but am getting a token mismatch error when I try to login a user. I'm not using a form, rather I am using an ajax call that logs in the user after google verification has been satisfied.

My error is: `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53`

My controller that is getting hit with the ajax call:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Email;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Google_Client; 
    use Auth;
    use App\User;
    class verify extends Controller
    {

    public function verifyIdToken(Request $request)
      {
    $user = User::where('name', 'Molly')->first();
        Auth::login($user);
        if (Auth::check($user))
{
    return response()->json(['Logged In' => "Yes!"]);
}
    }
      }
```

I don't get a response, just a 500 internal server error with the above error. I do see a laravel session cookie being returned however, so I am very confused as to what is going on. What is this token and why is it throwing an error?

For more information, my `routes.php` file is:

```
    if (Auth::guest()) {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
} else {
    Route::get('/', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
        return view('mainview');
    }]);
}
```

Edit: Basically I want the controller hit in the ajax call to verify the user was logged in, without any internal server error so that on a refresh, they are rerouted to the `mainview` not the `welcome` page.

Comment: Are you sending the token on the ajax call ?

Comment: @Meroje No. where would this even come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following method, From Docs.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: So I did this an the error is gone and I get a cookie set, but upon refreshing the homepage I still get `welcome` not `mainview`... any idea why?